# Variable 'varName' is not found on DBC database

Tags: foxpro, dbf, visual-foxpro

I have a DBC container with many DBF tables inside.

The format of the tables are different between them, like this:

tables with `b8_` on the name doesn't contain the column `'NUMEROSBIS3'` and tables with the `tsn_` on the name have the column `'NUMEROSBIS3'`

If i want to remove the table from the container i execute the next statement:

```
EXECSCRIPT([REMOVE TABLE tsn20150426])
```

With this statement the table is removed from the DBC container but if i perform a `select` statement like this:
`SELECT * FROM tsn20150426` then i get the error `Variable 'NUMEROS3BIS' is not found`. BUT if i perform `EXECSCRIPT([REMOVE TABLE b8_20130811])` (a table that doesn't contain the `'NUMEROS3BIS` column (removing the table) and then i perform `SELECT * FROM b8_20130811` i get the data with out errors!

What's the difference between this two actions? Why the table with the column `'NUMEROS3BIS'` (`tsn_` prefix on the table) get that error on the `select` statement and the other table (`b8_` prefix on the table) doesn't throw the error?

I have to say that in every action the physical file is never removed or moved or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant totally confirm, but what is probably happening is the REMOVE table just removes the table from the actual database container, but leaves the original table as a FREE-TABLE still in the directory.

Once a table is a "Free" table and not bound to a data dictionary, it no longer supports column names longer than 10 characters (original design maximum column name length).  So your column of "NUMEROSBIS3" is 11 characters and is thus truncated down to only "NUMEROSBIS" in the free table.

When querying your second table, since it does not have the 11-character column name, no error.  It just is coincidental that no other columns had names longer than 10 characters.

EDIT per comment.

If you STILL need the 11-character column name, an in-memory cursor result set can still have longer than 10 character column name.  So you would have to adjust you query something like

```
select ;
      T1.*, ;
      T1.NUMEROSBIS as NUMEROSBIS3 ;
   from ;
      tsn20150426 T1 ;
   into ;
      cursor C_SomeResultAlias readwrite
```

Then you'll still have the 10-character version AND the 11-character version to comply with the rest of your application logic.

Comment: OMG that's the problem! but i can't rename the column name because is part of a greater logic. What are my options? do i need to perform another command before the `SELECT` statement?